# Is there a way to display a div (that is expandable) within a form block via css?

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to work around the issue where you can't have a form within a form using current cross browser compatible html.  My possible workaround would be to have a div (with the contents of another form) outside of the form block and then use css to position it within the form.  Is there an elegant way to go about this?

Comment: well first question, why do you have a form within a form?

Comment: Why would you need to use a form inside a form? Is it because you are trying to reuse some html?

Comment: The elegant way is to have one form and handle the submissions using JavaScript.

Comment: Can we please ignore the fact about having a form within a form?  It is basically a requirement that I can't change.

Comment: well you already described the "elegant" way: to have 2 forms independent and play with their positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning on the form elements in the second form.